# Can't get value from input fields in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have this inputs

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="form-group">
<input type="number" value=""  min="1" max="100" id="{{ $product>product_id }}-qty" class="form-control {{ $product->product_id }}-qty">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="{{ $product->product_id }}-comment" ></textarea>
</div>
<button class="btn" onclick="addToCart({{ $product->product_id }})">
 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>

@endforeach
```

and this javascript function

```
function addToCart(productID){
    //alert(document.getElementById(productID+"-qty").value)
    var comment=jQuery("#"+productID+"-comment").val();
    alert(comment)
}
```

always return empty string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're using your function on button click .. you can start from the button like this

in js

```
function addToCart(el){
    var input_value = jQuery(el).prev('.form-group').prev('.form-group').find("input").val();
    var comment=jQuery(el).prev('.form-group').find("textarea").val();
    alert(comment)
}
```

in html

```
<button class="btn" onclick="addToCart(this)">
```

> Note : It will be better to wrap your code inside a div and use
>   `.closest()` and `.find()` instead of using `.prev()`

Comment: but if i have multiple input  how can i find them ?

Comment: multiple input with dynamic order

Comment: You're Welcome ya @ahmedmahmoudzidan .. ana hena law e7tagt ay 7aga tany  .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addToCart(productID){
    //alert(document.getElementById(productID+"-qty").value)
    var comment=jQuery("#"+productID+"-comment").val();
    alert(comment)
}
```

You're getting empty because there is no element with the id="27-product_slug"

Comment: Are you getting the right Id in the function? What does

    function addToCart(productID){
        console.log(productID) 
    }

Comment: Are you using two -- ?

Your html is 1--comment, your javascript is 1-comment

Comment: i figured every thing i think problem it doesn't get my input and every time got default value ,

Comment: i also tried to set a default value  and i got that value .

Comment: where is the two -- , please see my question again .

Comment: Yeah there isn't. Just looked like two. My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the correct id is returned.

```
function addToCart(productID){
    alert(productID);
}
```

also, put the code before the  and after the **jquery** source file, and prefer to be like that:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

...Your-Functions...

});
```